# numba nopython mode "Undefined variable '$313.3'"

Tags: python, numpy, numba

This is my code to construct minimum trees from an image (`f` is an image provided by scipy)

It is the foundation of a seam carving program that I am writing.

This snippet works as intended in normal python. When I use `@numba.jit` without `nopython=True`, it also works (with a ~200% performance improvement!), but that is in object mode.

When I try to use `nopython=True` mode it does not compile and I get the error:

```
Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Undefined variable '$313.3'
```

I don't understand why this will not compile, because I do not see anything that could be undefined.

```
from numba import jit
from scipy import misc
import numba

f = misc.face()
@jit(nopython=True)
def explorethisx(inar, x):
    places = []
    places.append((x,0))
    x1,y1 = x,0
    s = numba.int64(0)
    co = 0
    #for _ in range( 799):

    while co != numba.int16(799):
        co += 1
        a1,a2,a3 = 999,999,999
        a1 = inar[y1 + 1][x1-1][1]
        a2 = inar[y1 + 1][x1][1]
        a3 = inar[y1 + 1][x1 + 1][1]
        m = a1
        ch = -1
        if m > a2:
            m = a2
            ch = 0
        if m > a3:
            m = a3
            ch = 1
        x1 = x1 + ch
        y1 = y1 + 1
        s += inar[y1][x1][1]
        places.append((x1,y1))
    return([s, places])
explorethisx(f,3)
explorethisx.inspect_types()
```

Numba is a really cool project, and I am impressed by performance improvements even in python object mode.

Comment: Just as a general tip, it is much faster to access array elements using `x[i,j,k]` rather than `x[i][j][k]`. So for example, use `inar[y1 + 1,x1-1,1]` and similar throughout. This sped up my benchmark of your code by almost 1.6x. This is true for all numpy/numba operations on ndarrays.

Comment: @JoshAdel may I ask how you ran a benchmark? The only way I know is to use cProfile.

Comment: I tend to profile in a Jupyter notebook using the `%timeit` magic. When profiling Numba code especially you need to throw out the first execution of the jitted function since that will include the compilation time which you only pay for once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception message is misleading. It's just that [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) only supports homogeneous lists, so when you try to return `[s, places]` you return a list containing one "integer" and one "list of tuples of integers" which isn't homogeneous anymore.

Note that this minimal example already demonstrates that exception:

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def test():
    places = []
    places.append((1, 2))
    places.append((2, 3))
    return [10, places]

>>> test()
...
TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Undefined variable '$0.12'
```

You could simply return a tuple:

```
return (s, places)
```

instead of the old

```
return([s, places])
```

Even though this compiles - the function contains an out-of-bounds memory access (I had a segfault) when calling the functions so you definetly need to check your memory access as well.

Comment: That's crazy, why does it give the error with `$`? I've been trying to debug `f` looking for a string.

Comment: In other words, I don't doubt that you've pinpointed the issue, but the error message is _really_ misleading to me. I'm trying to learn `numba` and this has no doubt saved me a huge headache. Such a strange way to report mixed types.

Comment: Leaky abstraction. Probably that's a placeholder in the numba code.

Comment: I have no idea why they chose that exception message, it's not _really_ misleading though - I would rather say it's not helpful _at all_. Nevertheless I had the exception last week so I remembered what caused it and how to fix it. (Note that they already filed a bug report to improve the error message: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2237).

Comment: For me the exception was misleading because I was looking for the string, I overlooked the nested list.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel dumb now, I remember reading the bit about homogenous lists in the guide, I should have realized.